# Were there rabbis who supported the patrilineal descent?

Tags: halacha, am-yisrael-jewish-nation

Many are accustomed to the fact that in rabbinic Judaism a Jew is one who is born of a Jewish woman.

But were there opposite opinions? Poskim of post-Talmudic time are of also interest.

Comment: Not fully, but related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26066/27180 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69863/27180

Comment: Why is this a "provocative question"?

Comment: Here's why: the decision on matrilineal descent was ruled by Ezra, upon his return from Babylon, in the 5th century BCE. Rabbinic Judaism developed in the 2nd century CE out of the Pharisee movement that started around the Maccabean revolt in the 2nd century BCE. Therefore there are no rabbinic arguments on this specific issue, Ezra's decree was accepted unanimously.

Comment: @al berko the Gemara derives it from a passuk in the Torah https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.68b?lang=bi

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Biblical Judaism (pre-Babylon exile) was patrilineal in all senses. IIRC, not a single case of conversion is mentioned in the scriptures, while most of our foremothers were explicitly gentile.

Comment: @Chatzkel The Gemara merely finds scriptural support for already existing practice. Note that the verse does not say that explicitly, so the rule is relied on the verse posteriourly, not "derived from it" IMHO. This is how I learn the difference between "learns from" and "relies on". For example, "not in heaven" and "Pikuach Nefesh" are both a posterior reliance, not teaching.

Comment: Note that AlBerko is rejecting the rabbinic Judaism approach

Comment: @AlBerko Conversion is discussed - for example circumcisions with Abraham. It is possible to argue no-one was "Jewish" until they "converted". Though there might be no scriptural reference to women converting, it would be hard to argue they didn't if the men did.

Comment: FWIW, karaites follow patrilineal descent.

Comment: @robev How? Both my examples were instituted at some specific time by referring to a verse(s) while other rabbis did not accept it.

Comment: You failed to provide any proof that these were *instituted* and it was at *some specific time*. Traditional Judaism always took it for granted that this is the law that Hashem gave Moshe. You're denying the oral Torah. Which rabbis didn't accept matrilineal descent? Name one.

Comment: 1) "not a single case of conversion is mentioned in the scriptures" Literally Rus. 2) Vayikra 24:10 is an explicit reference to exclusively matrilineal descent. The Ben Ish Mitzri was a Jew because of his Jewish mother, despite being a non-Jew patrilineally.

Comment: Wasn't there a tanna or amorah that paskend this way (obscure source?)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Chatzkel (see comment) Kiddushin 68b it appears clear through a number of verses that Judaism is determined by the mother. There does not appear an opinion that argues on this point.

I personally don't recall an opinion that stated that "Jewishness" is decided patrilineally.

In regard to the father:

This question is mostly discussed in the third and fourth perek of Kiddushin. There are issues in regard to lineage (mamzer etc...) that do include Patrilineal descent as well in to the equation. These questions affect who the child as a Jew may marry.

Similary what tribe a person belongs to is decided by patrilineal descent. For example a Kohen or Levi is decided through the father.

Comment: The Gemara Kiddushin 68B is pretty clear that Jewishness is determined with the mother alone. https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.68b?lang=bi

Comment: Thanks. I will include it in the answer.